# Slim php, stop, die after sending a 403 response status code in a small middleware

Tags: php, slim

I created a small middleware function for slim php framework that checks if the user is authenticated or not, like so.

```
function authenticate($app) {
    return function() use ($app) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $response = array();
            array_push($response, array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => 'You are not logged in.'
                )
            );
            echoRes(403, $response);
        }
    };
}
```

What happens is that if I tried to insert it in a route like this:

```
$app->get('/', authenticate($app), function() use ($app){
     echoRes(200, 'hello world!');
});
```

The `echoRes` function

```
function echoRes($code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $app->status($code);
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

What happens is that it will continue to give me a status code of `200` even when not authenticated, even I kill it using `die()`;

```
function authenticate($app) {
    return function() use ($app) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $response = array();
            array_push($response, array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => 'You are not logged in.'
                )
            );
            echoRes(403, $response);
            die();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use $app->notfound() or $app->halt(403) to halt execution. There is no need to set the status code as it is set by these functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using version 2.2.0 (*I'm not sure if applicable in higher version*) and also have to add JSON response after setting 403 response status, then you may use `$app->stop()`. Using `$app->halt(arg)` removes the contents of the body.

Answer (score 0):

With Slim 3.0, halt() and stop() does not exists anymore.
Reference: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/upgrade.html#removal-of-stophalt

You need to use ->withJson():

```
return $response->withJson([
  'error' => true,
  'message' => 'You are not logged in.'
], 403);
```

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is that sometimes other functions are still executed, so you can't guarantee the program stopped when calling this.

Comment: Since there is a return, no other functions will be executed.